# problem merging multiple images and one audio into a video

Tags: ffmpeg

I got 22 png images named like this pics1.png, pics2.png ... pics22.png

I also got a wav file of duration 00:02:25

I am trying to merge them into a video using ffmpeg, but the problem is that audio keeps falling back (lags behind the image)

In the video, the audio is still explaining image number 20, while image on the screen is image number 22, pics22.png...

I got many more videos to make this way, sometimes images are over 100, and audio is many minutes long.

No matter what calculation I use, I cannot get these audios and images merged properly into a video...

Please tell me ffmpeg command I can use in "general" to do this.

This is the command I am using so far.

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -framerate 115/65 -i pics%d.png -i rmt.wav -ar 44100 -s 800x600 video.flv
```

Comment: Is each image meant to be shown for the same amount of time?

Comment: Yes, each image is meant to be shown for the same amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For output duration X with N slides, command should be

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate N/X -i pics%d.png -i rmt.wav -ar 44100 -r 25 -s 800x600 video.flv
```

So, for a duration of 2:25 --> 145 seconds, and 22 images, command should be

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 22/145 -i pics%d.png -i rmt.wav -r 25 -ar 44100 -s 800x600 video.flv
```

Comment: Thankyou for this command! Sometimes the duration will be less than number of images, like 145 seconds, and 300 images. Will this work in that case too? FRAMERATE will be less than 1 in this case (0.5), is that allowed? Thanks

Comment: Added output rate to avoid low fps output; also corrected expr.